# Как ведёт себя цикл в js

Tags: javascript

**Как ведёт себя данный цикл в js:**

```
 for(i=0,j=10;i<j;i++,j--)
```

Comment: А что, в других языках наблюдаются отличия в поведении `for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. i=0; j=10;
2. до тех пор, пока i < j
3. i++; j--;

**по итерациям:**

1. i=0; j=10;
2. i=1; j=9;
3. i=2; j=8;
4. i=3; j=7;
5. i=4; j=6;
6. i=5; j=5; - условие не проходит, выходим из цикла

**p.s.** Тут особенность **i++** и **j--** в том что они сначала проверят условие, зайдут в цикл со старыми значениями, потом выполнятся